# Switch to popup windows in cucumber, capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara, popupwindow

In RSpec i can use such code switch to popup window, [link](http://thinkingeek.com/2013/04/27/capybara-pop-windows-paypal-sandbox/), How can i do such thing in Cucumber steps?

```
login_window = page.driver.find_window('PPA_identity_window')
    main_window = page.driver.find_window('')

    # We use this to execute the next instructions in the popup window
    page.within_window(login_window) do
      #Normally fill in the form and log in
      fill_in 'email', :with => "<your paypal sandbox username>"
      fill_in 'password', :with => "<your paypal sandbox password>"
      click_button 'Log In'
    end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there is a cucumber/capybara way to do this as such.

But you can still change the window using selenium driver commands like this:

```
    #Get the main window handle
    main = page.driver.browser.window_handles.first
    #Get the popup window handle
    popup = page.driver.browser.window_handles.last

    #Then switch control between the windows
    page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(popup)
```

EDIT:
Andrews answer below is the correct answer now since new DSL changes were implemented.

Comment: Capybara now provides a DSL for interacting with popup windows. See my answer below.

Comment: Please use Andrew's answer below as this implementation will cause you an error when you want to access the main window after the modal window closes.

Comment: If you're using Capybara, don't go with this method especially if you are going to use the Chrome driver. You will encounter an exception when using the switch_to_window() method. https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1861. Use the answer below by Andrew.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) in your Cucumber steps to interact with popup windows:

```
login_window = window_opened_by do
  click_button 'Open Login Window'
end
within_window(login_window) do
  fill_in :email, with: "email@example.com"
  fill_in :password, with: "password"
  click_button 'Log In'
end
```

Comment: best answer by far

Comment: For a capybara tech used, this one is the best fitted example

Answer (score -2):

In a simple way we can do so, without within_window and without selenium natives.

```
page.switch_to_window page.windows.first

page.switch_to_window page.windows.last
```

or

```
page.switch_to_window page.windows[0]

page.switch_to_window page.windows[-1]
```

0 - is the first window
-1  - is the last window

**windows** function return an array of all windows.

Another way, using the title of page.

page.switch_to_window { title == 'Google' }