# How interacting popup using selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I would like to enter datas in the login boxes
[image: image description here]

Comment: Is it a system login box or just some fields on the page? What causes the "popup" to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pop up is coming as new window then you can refer this link which is explaining your problem nicely: [Switch to popup windows in cucumber, capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983684/switch-to-popup-windows-in-cucumber-capybara)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to switch the driver into the new window and then select the elements just like any other element.

I'm not sure on ruby how it is but the window switching should look something like this:

```
driver.switch_to.window driver.window_handles.at(1)
```