# How to handle dynamic elements with cucumber and capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

([Click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akGJW.jpg)) I am working on an project to write a scenario to test login feature. For some reason capybara is not accessing dynamic elements.

Steps to Reproduce:

1) visit Redfin.com(for example)

2) click on Sign in button

3) a dynamic popup dialog appears

4) click on "continue with email" and try and enter details and clicking on submit.

I am not able to find any of the elements with find(#) and inturn not able to click on submit or enter details.

Also I believe the webapp is build with React.
Please do let me know how to handle this.

```
<div class="emailSignInButtonWrapper" style="position: relative;">
  <button class="button Button tertiary emailSignInButton v3" type="button" tabindex="0" data-rf-test-name="submitButton">
    <span>
      <span class="signInText">Continue with Email</span>
    </span>
  </button>
```

Comment: I don't know how the code look like, an example would be good. However, as you mentioned the app is written in React, my first guess would be to switch to the `Capybara.javascript_driver` using `js: true`. You might find this useful. https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Comment: @hyphenbash For the html code you could visit the (redfin.com website),

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch to popup windows in cucumber, capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983684/switch-to-popup-windows-in-cucumber-capybara)

Comment: @maxpleaner : I added a link to an image for reference, I am sure that it is not a pop up window. it is on the same page .

Comment: was my comment useful? it seems like we're still not sure what your problem is. Hence why I asked for a piece of code where your problem is. Unless you were only looking for a generic answer as I gave above?

Comment: @hyphenbash I have added the piece of code and I need to click on "Continue with email" . Is this helpful of would it be better If I post the complete html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the elements you are talking about have ids so a CSS find using `#<id>` (`find('#my_button').click`) isn't going to work.  However to click that button you should just be able to do

```
click_button('Continue with Email') # case of the text matters
```

or

```
click_button(class: 'emailSignInButton')
```

This all assumes you are using a driver with Capybara that supports JS - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers

Here's code that shows it works if using a JS capable driver

```
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome)
session.visit "https://www.redfin.com"

session.click_link('Sign In', href: nil)

session.click_button('Continue with Email')
```

Comment: I have tried using these with no luck, getting an error _Unable to find visible button nil with classes [emailSignInButton] (Capybara::ElementNotFound)_

Comment: @user8673269 then you either aren’t actually using selenium for these tests or you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time too low for the hardware you’re testing on.  Try taking a screenshot to see what the actual page state is

Comment: @user8673269 Code added showing that it works - most likely you aren't actually using selenium as indicated by your tags

Comment: Hey @ThomasWalpole what does passing `href: nil` do as an option?  I thought that was interesting.  I could not get `click_link('Sign In')` to work on its own either.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole: Thank you for the solution works like a charm!

Comment: @Phil By default `click_link` will only click on links (which by HTML spec have to have an `href` attribute - without they are technically placeholders).  By specifying `href: nil` click_link will click on placeholders (<a> elements with no href attribute) - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find_link-instance_method

Comment: Thanks so much once again, @ThomasWalpole!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me on the redfin site:

```
scenario "bring up signup form on redfin" do
  visit 'https://www.redfin.com'
  find('a', :text => 'Sign In').click
  click_button('Continue with Email')
end
```